# Android Half screen of the List view is not responding

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an application in which I am using a list view

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,titles));
```

now what I get is like this[image]

as you can see when I press on the text it senses it and not anywhere on the row beyond that.Is there any way I can work this thing out other than using my custom xml file(resource) for list.

Xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MovieCritics" >

    <fragment class="com.example.moviecritics.FragmentMovieName"
        android:id="@+id/movie_name"
        android:name="android.support.v4.app.ListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and it's working fine in landscape mode

Comment: use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 instead of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1. Remove activated from it.

Comment: post some of your layout.

Comment: @sipka that dosen't work

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:listSelector` in your ListView